# Symfony2 Doctrine findBy causes Fatal error

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

When I use the findBy function instead of find within a smyfony service container it causes an error.

```
$site = $this->em->getRepository('...')->find($id);
$site->getTitle();
```

Works fine. If I use findBy

```
$site = $this->em->getRepository('...')->findByTitle($id);
$site->getTitle();
```

I get an error "Fatal error: Call member function getTitle();".

What do I have to change?

Comment: Have you set the @ID in entity annotations to the Title field? Find searches by the entity ID. I have never seen a case where it is not defined, but I suppose it would return NULL, which explains you error

Comment: It did var_dump($site); an it returns object(...\Entity\Site)

Comment: Interesting.... check the generated DQL

Comment: Is the annotation correct like this?
**
     * @var integer $siteId
     * @ORM\Column(name="siteId", type="integer")
     */

Comment: I resolved the error by using findOneBy instead of findBy.

Answer (score 0):

No, the annotation is not correct.

You have to use the @Id identifier in order for find function to work.

Also, I strongly suggest you define ids everywhere, because joining will not work correctly without it (unless you mean to write every join condition by hand).

Yes, if you want just one entity, findOneBy is the way to go. Also note that find is just a shortcut for findOneById, where Id is the column you referenced with the @Id annotation.

Check out the [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys).

Also I would suggest you to edit the question and tags, if someone else stumbles upon this. This has nothing to do with Symfony, it is strictly Doctrine related.